# Linkyfing european phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am searching for a regex that replaces some random phone number with an `<a href>`. The phone numbers should mainly be Swedish, but non-Swedish should also be supported.

I would like to support the following formats:

**(0 + 9 numbers)**

- +46xxxxxxxxx
- 0046xxxxxxxxx
- 0xxxxxxxxx

**(0 + 8 numbers)**

- +46xxxxxxxx
- 0046xxxxxxxx
- 0xxxxxxxx

**(0 + 7 numbers)**

- +46xxxxxxx
- 0046xxxxxxx
- 0xxxxxxx

Usually they are formatted as well according to the format from [this](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefonnummer) page, however I have no requirement to support that (although it would be great).

What I have tried so far, is tried a lot of regex. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269151/406677) I tried to make my own version of it, however I can't seem to get it to work. 
The closest I have come is with this regex, yet it removes too much:

```
/( |^|>)((((\+|00)[0-9]{2} ?(\(0\))?)|0)([0-9]{2}-? ?[0-9]{7})|([0-9]{3}-? ?[0-9]{6})|([0-9]{1}-? ?[0-9]{8}))( |$|<)/gi
```

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xAXy4/1/

The goal of my script is to identify phone numbers and make them an `<a href="tel:XXX">XXX</a>` link. 
My current code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var patt=/( |^|>)((((\+|00)[0-9]{2} ?(\(0\))?)|0)([0-9]{2}-? ?[0-9]{7})|([0-9]{3}-? ?[0-9]{6})|([0-9]{1}-? ?[0-9]{8}))( |$|<)/gi

    $('*','body').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(patt,'<a href="tel:$2">$2</a>'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe http://www.regexper.com/ will come in handy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to capture pretty much all the allowed formats in your test page.

[image]

```
pattern: /([^\d\+]|^|>)((((\+|00)(\d\d)\s*(\(0\))?)|0)(\s*\d){7,9})([^\d\+]|$|<)/gi
replace: '$1<a href="tel:$2">$2</a>$9'
```

[Fork of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzt96/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work?

[image: Regexper.com]

```
var regex = /((\+\d{2}|00\d{2}|0)\d{7,9})/g,
    text = 'hello call me +46123456789';

text = text.replace(regex, function(all) {
    return '<a href="tel:'+all+'">'+all+'</a>';
}); 

console.log(text);
```

But as with your test case this just mess stuff up: http://jsfiddle.net/xAXy4/2/

Comment: Thanks for the regexper link! Also, you code works nicely, but I went with hsan's example, since it covers more. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `/(?:\+46|0046|0)\d{7,9}/` :

```
['+46123456789', '0046123456789', '0123456789',
 '+4612345678', '004612345678', '012345678',
 '+461234567' ,'00461234567', '01234567'].map (
   function (t) { 
     return /(?:\+46|0046|0)\d{7,9}/.test (t);
   });
```

-->  [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]